# Make automated test cases for system which saves unique data without deleting records manually from database

Tags: testing, coded-ui-tests

I want to make UI  automated test cases for system using Coded UI Test . and the test case have long life cycle, like:

1. Register  farm [ RMH-22 ]
2. Register for two houses in this farm [ H-1 , H-2 ]
3. Ensuring that they have been saved in data base by clicking on the search button in the system and search for [RMH-22]

when I playback this test case it doesn't work correctly because the system have saved this farm [ RMH-22 ] in the data base during recording.

Taking in consideration that the  system saves unique code for farms.

Is there any solution to automate such test cases without deleting the database records manually before playback test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem, as I understand it, is that the test is recorded using fixed names for farm and house, so those names are entered into the database. When the test is run again those same names are used but they are already in the database.

One approach is to ensure different names are used in each test run. I suggest creating a farm name and house names that include the date and time of the test run. So create names such as `FarmYYYYMMDDHHMMSS`, `H1YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` and `H2YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. If needed it would be easy to compress the date and time to make a shorter name. Generate the names in the code and then write values into fields of the `...Params` classes, much like is done in a data driven Coded UI tests.

As an alternative, some people suggest appending serial numbers (or letters), but that would mean keeping track of which number have already been used. Hence I would avoid that approach.

Update about compression of names.

If the project and the need for testing is short lived then parts or all of the year might be omitted. If you can guarantee that testing will not be needed after 2020 then just keep the year of the decade (currently '3'). Rather than `YYMM` you could use day of the year, three digits in the range 1 to 366. You could encode the date as number of days since some start date; the number need not be precisely correct, just easy to calculate and giving suitable non-overlapping values. Eg `(year - 2013) * 366 + day_of_year` Rather than `HHMMSS` you could use second of the day, in the range 0 to 60*60*24 , ie 0 to 86400. Rather than using decimal digits for the name you could use a base 36 (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_36 ) encoding. Taken together these should better than halve the number of characters required for a date-time part of the name.

Comment: Thanks For your answer .

but U mean I have to make them unique  in the code  by appending to the names the time of run test ?!  but How will I compress it ?!

Comment: Any advice on compression needs more context. What do you want to achieve? What name lengths can be used? What is the minimum time interval between test executions?

Comment: Really, I faced this problem and I don't know what will be the restrictions on the name. 

but from your answer I have figured that the farm name will be something like : 
Farm201393181643 and i think this name is long  but till this moment I don't have any restriction on the name.

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu My experience of real farm names is that they can be quite long. An uncompressed name for now, as I type this comment, might be `Farm201309211156`. I have added some ideas on compression to the answer.

Comment: Alternatively, if you know beforehand the farm names and houses you want to add, then you could put that info in a CSV or an XML and create a data driven coded UI to populate your database with that information.

Comment: @LuFaMa That does not work here for the reasons stated in the original question and elaborated in the first paragraph of this answer. Basically once the names have been added to the database they cannot be added again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same situation occur in a CodedUITest system I built for a healthcare software product I work on. Basically it would throw off an exception after the first test successfully completed and the second one was starting up, and all the rest would end up failing as well.

Kept talking about a threading issue when it ended up being memory. It would end up building a large and complex database by the end of the test that I wished I could use again but because of how these tests work you will have to just wipe the entire database, and not only that but force a garbage collection on the entire map and its contents by setting all values to null to flag for collection and then forcing the collection to take place.

It sucks, I know trust me, but in a case like this it's better to just wipe the whole thing and rebuild all the data you have gathered every single test.

Comment: U mean I have to wipe the database records after recording the testcase  then playback the testcase ?!